# Hacer INSERT en un ciclo anidado con PHP

Tags: php, sql, insert, odbc

estoy realizando una consulta a un XML usando ciclos foreach, tengo un ciclo anidado para obtener los datos que están en otro nivel del documento, pero necesito realizar un INSERT de datos que estan en distintos niveles del documento, ¿como puedo realizar el INSERT extrayendo los datos de distintos niveles del foreach?.

Este es el código que estoy usando para iterar sobre el XML.

```
foreach($elements as $element){
    echo 'Order Id: '.$element->OrderId.'<br>';
    echo 'Order Number: '.$element->OrderNumber.'<br>';
    // EL CICLO RECORRE EL CAMPO DE DIRECCION PARA EXTRAER LA DIRECCION DEL CLIENTE
    $elem =  utf8_decode($element->AddressBilling);
    $dir = explode('|', $elem);
    for($i=0; $i < count($dir); $i++){
        echo $dir[$i].'<br>';
    }
    // EL CICLO RECORRE EL CAMPO DE ITEMS PARA EXTRAER LOS DATOS DE ITEMS
    $items = $element->Items->orderItem;

    foreach($items as $item){
        echo '*********** ITEMS DE COMPRA ************'.'<br>';
        echo 'Item ID: '.$item->OrderItemId.'<BR>';
        echo 'Shop ID: '.$item->ShopId.'<BR>';
        echo 'Order ID: '.$item->OrderId.'<BR>';
        echo 'SKU: '.$item->Sku.'<BR>';
        echo 'SHOP SKU: '.$item->ShopSku.'<BR>';
        echo 'Name: '.$item->Name.'<BR>';
        echo 'Tax Amount: '.$item->TaxAmount.'<BR>';
        echo 'Tracking Code: '.$item->TrackingCode.'<BR>';
        echo 'Item Price: '.$item->ItemPriceFull.'<BR>';
        echo 'Location ID: '.$item->LocationId.'<BR>';
        echo 'Discount: '.$item->Discount.'<BR>';
        echo 'Item Price: '.$item->ItemPrice.'<BR>';
        echo 'CreatedAt: '.$item->CreatedAt.'<BR>';
        echo 'UpdatedAt: '.$item->UpdatedAt.'<BR>';
        echo 'Promised Shipping Times: '.$item->PromisedShippingTimes.'<BR>';
        echo 'Shipping Amount: '.$item->ShippingAmount.'<BR>';
        echo 'Status: '.$item->Status.'<BR>';
        echo 'Shipment Provider: '.$item->ShipmentProvider.'<BR>';
    }
}
```

Comment: te recomendaría clonar en ram el archivo y ir actualizando todo en el clonado, al finalizar sobre escribir el archivo para mayor seguridad ...

Answer (score 0):

No es muy eficiente, pero en el mismo bucle del foreach puedes meter una sentencia SQL que haga el insert en la DB, algo tipo, recuerda tener configurada tu conexión SQL antes de ejecutar la sentencia:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO nombre_tabla (nombre de los campos en los que insertar valores del foreach) VALUES (variables del foreach)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día.
Dentro del foreach de items podrías hacer:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO ('order_id', 'order_number', 'direccion', 'item_id', 'shop_id') VALUES ($element->OrderId, $element->OrderNumber, $dir[0], $item->OrderItemId, $item->ShopId);"
```

Suponiendo que estes trabajando con mysql y que los campos en tu tabla se llamen como en el ejemplo.
Tambien tener en cuenta que podrías tener varias direcciones de las cuales solo estoy guardando la primera